# Default template not found

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I have just put the fineuploader CSS and JS files in my project and am getting a javascript error:

```
JavaScript TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null - ...fine-uploader/fine-uploader.js:7238
```

Edit: which is this part of the fine-uploader.js file:

```
qq.extend(this, {
    render: function() {
        log("Rendering template in DOM.");

        generatedThumbnails = 0;

        container.innerHTML = templateHtml.template; //<--this line
```

I have the qq-template script in my html (php) file, pretty much as the vanilla template supplied:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/fine-uploader/fine-uploader-new.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
        <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
            <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
                <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
                <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                <div>Upload a file</div>
            </div>
                <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
                    <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
                    <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
                </span>
            <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
                <li>
                    <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                        <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                    <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                    <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                    <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                    <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                    <button class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="qq-btn qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">Retry</button>
                    <button class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">Delete</button>
                    <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>

            <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                    <button class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>

            <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <input type="text">
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>
        </div>
    </script>

    <title>Fine Uploader default UI</title>
</head>
<body>

<a HREF="javacript:void(0)" id="selectFiles">Add files</a>
<script>

var uploader = new qq.FineUploader(
    {
        debug: true, button: document.getElementById('selectFiles')

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome console log:

```
[Fine Uploader 5.2.1] Parsing template
fine-uploader.js:244 [Fine Uploader 5.2.1] Template parsing complete
fine-uploader.js:244 [Fine Uploader 5.2.1] Rendering template in DOM.
fine-uploader.js:7238 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of nullqq.extend.render @ fine-uploader.js:7238qq.FineUploader @ fine-uploader.js:6576(anonymous function) @ (index):81
fine-uploader.js:244 [Fine Uploader 5.2.1] Received 1 files.
fine-uploader.js:244 [Fine Uploader 5.2.1] Attempting to validate image.
fine-uploader.js:7271 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of nullqq.extend.addFile @ fine-`uploader.js:7271qq.uiPrivateApi._addToList @ fine-uploader.js:6278qq.uiPrivateApi._onSubmit @ fine-uploader.js:6004qq.basePrivateApi._onSubmitCallbackSuccess @ fine-uploader.js:3005qq.bind @ fine-uploader.js:695qq.basePrivateApi._handleCheckedCallback @ fine-uploader.js:2536qq.basePrivateApi._upload @ fine-uploader.js:3252(anonymous function) @ fine-uploader.js:3122qq.extend.then @ fine-uploader.js:1096qq.basePrivateApi._onValidateCallbackSuccess @ fine-uploader.js:3120qq.bind @ fine-uploader.js:695qq.basePrivateApi._handleCheckedCallback @ fine-uploader.js:2536qq.basePrivateApi._onValidateBatchCallbackSuccess @ fine-uploader.js:3085qq.bind @ fine-uploader.js:695qq.basePrivateApi._handleCheckedCallback @ fine-uploader.js:2536qq.basePrivateApi._prepareItemsForUpload @ fine-uploader.js:3141qq.uiPrivateApi._prepareItemsForUpload @ fine-uploader.js:6388qq.basePublicApi.addFiles @ fine-uploader.js:1666qq.basePrivateApi._onInputChange @ fine-uploader.js:2984qq.UploadButton.onChange @ fine-uploader.js:2184(anonymous function) @ fine-uploader.js:1277`
```

Comment: Where is your code which produce this error?

Comment: Post your code, template, and browser console logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Fine Uploader configuration is invalid, as you have not specified a container element for Fine Uploader to render the template.

You'll need to add a container element, and then reference it in your config via [the `element` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-ui.html#element).